# Accessing files outside project folder

Tags: angular, docker, directory

I am working on an angular 5 application where I am having some issues access some files. Let me give show you how my project is set up so you can see the issue.

- root

  - desired_files
  - angularApp
  - app_generating_files

So my issue is I need to be able to access the files in the `desired_files`folder from my angular application. The files that go into this folder are generated by the other project also in my root. If you have any ideas on how I can do this it would be greatly appreciated.

(I am using Docker, on the `app_generating_files` project, so I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to try and use that)

Answer (score 0):

The beginning to the answer you're looking for is here : [Angular-cli: How can I access images outside of the assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710642/angular-cli-how-can-i-access-images-outside-of-the-assets-folder)

In the glob object, be sure to add *allowOutsideOutDir* :

```js
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "../../path/to/files",
  "output": "./assets/outside-assets",
  "allowOutsideOutDir": true
}
```

For example, if you have an image named test.jpg in the directory  '*../../path/to/files*' you can include it in your project using the markup

```
<img src="assets/outside-assets/test.jpg" alt="not found">
```

Make sure the local version of your ng-cli is 1.5.0 as newer versions don't support *allowOutsideOutDir* as discussed here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8783

Comment: this binding is run-time or compile time?