# Angular 8: can not show new uploaded image without rebuilding the project

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, image-uploading, rebuild

When adding an image by nodejs in Angular project's assets folder Angular needs a rebuild to show the image by path, how can I get images without a rebuild?

Comment: Hi Arsen Galloghlyan, can you provide more information, for example what is your build process ?

Comment: ng serve in Angular (or only ctrl+s in my editor to rebuild it automatically)

Comment: The images are successfully adding in the assets folder, but angular doesn't recognize them until I rebuild the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you are talking about ng serve and not actual deployment.

The assets are meant to be static updated at build time (ng build or ng serve).

I would upload the images to a different directory outside of angular and fetch them from there in your angular app as is described [at this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47880056/accessing-files-outside-project-folder)

Comment: Yes I am talking about ng serve. And what about saving images in the database (base64). Is it a good practice?

Comment: Depends on usage. Databases were traditionally used but nowadays something like blob storage would make sense. CDN could also be used. Always depends on the case

Comment: I want to vote but I am still not allowed to vote because of my reputation (I'm new here :) )